# How to Format Lists of Strings and Dictionaries for Email Body in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, formatting, string-formatting

I'm working on a Python script where I need to format three different types of lists into a string that will be used as the body of an email. The lists are as follows:

**A list of strings:**

```
a = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
```

**A list of dictionaries, each containing a single key-value pair:**

```
b = [{'IP': '1.1.1.1'}, {'IP': '2.2.2.2'}, {'IP': '3.3.3.3'}]
```

**A list of dictionaries with multiple key-value pairs:**

```
c = [{'ID': 'dasfsdfs', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'Name': 'me'}, {'ID': 'qwrfgvzx', 'IP': '2.2.2.2', 'Name': 'you'}]
```

I want to format these lists so that each element (or key-value pair) appears on a separate line in the email body. Here's the structure I'm aiming for:

```
a_var -->
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

b_var -->
IP: 1.1.1.1
IP: 2.2.2.2
IP: 3.3.3.3

c_var -->
ID: dasfsdfs
IP: 1.1.1.1
Name: me

ID: qwrfgvzx
IP: 2.2.2.2
Name: you
```

I'm attempting to use inline for loops within an f-string to create this formatted string, but I'm not sure how to correctly apply this for each list, especially for the list of dictionaries with multiple key-value pairs.

```
my_email = f'''
a_var -->\n{inline for loop for {a}}

b_var -->\n{inline for loop for {b}}

c_var -->\ninline for loop for {c}}
'''
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way to achieve this formatting in Python?

Comment: Have you read on `' '.join()` and `List Comprehension`? If not, these may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Two more hints in addition to Harshit Gupta's hint: 1. iterate over `dict.items()`. 2. Since you want to use the *inline loop* 3 times, you should define it as a function. At that point, it is irrelevant whether you can write the loop in a single line (e.g. `[f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in d.items()]`) or in multiple lines.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Socowi thanks for editing. I missed some parts of `markdown` when writing the question.

Comment: @HarshitGupta I'll read it. I didn't know that.

Comment: @HarshitGupta all of the above list are results of list comprehension. I did `list.append()` for all of the above list.

Comment: @Rogers, Welcome to StackOverflow! 
I believe that you are looking to make use of your lists named **a**, **b**, and **c** within your *format string* using some relevant inline for-loop (also known as List Comprehension in Python 3).
I would suggest you to improve your code snippet above the expected output to show the actual inline for-loop that you have tried, or clear it in your question that you are looking for what inline for loops to make use of for each of **a**, **b** and **c** lists to get their separate line output to match the expected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want output like this:

```
a_var -->
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

b_var -->
IP: 1.1.1.1
IP: 2.2.2.2
IP: 3.3.3.3

c_var -->
ID: dasfsdfs
IP: 1.1.1.1
Name: me

ID: qwrfgvzx
IP: 2.2.2.2
Name: you
```

**For List `a:`**

- This list "`a`" would contain '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', etc.
- To achieve that: you're joining the strings with a new line char `\n` - basically it's like you are manually pressing enter each time.

**For List b:**

- This one is the one which contains dictionary, each which has "IP" `key`
- To achieve that: going through each dict with "IP" `key`, you then write it as "IP" followed by key, again you're at the end joining it with new line char.

**For List c:**

- This one represents dictionary again, but now it's with multiple `key` values (ID, IP, Name).
- To achieve that: Well, this one is a bit of harder one assuming that you're new to python, you are going to loop through each dict in list,.inside that loop you're going again through each key-value pair in it, you're combining them and joining them, but this time you're basically adding extra new line char, why? Because this is assuring that there's blank line between each set of ID, IP and Name.

To give you an idea:

```
a = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
b = [{'IP': '1.1.1.1'}, {'IP': '2.2.2.2'}, {'IP': '3.3.3.3'}]
c = [{'ID': 'dasfsdfs', 'IP': '1.1.1.1', 'Name': 'me'}, {'ID': 'qwrfgvzx', 'IP': '2.2.2.2', 'Name': 'you'}]

a_formatted = '\n'.join(a)

b_formatted = '\n'.join([f"IP: {d['IP']}" for d in b])

c_formatted = '\n\n'.join(['\n'.join([f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in d.items()]) for d in c])

formatted_email = f'''
a_var -->
{a_formatted}

b_var -->
{b_formatted}

c_var -->
{c_formatted}
'''

print(formatted_email)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`jinja`](https://github.com/pallets/jinja)'s templates in which you can incorporate [loop](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/switching/#loops)s ?

You can make a [`Template`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Template), shape it the way you want and finally [`render`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Template.render) it :

```
# pip install Jinja2
from jinja2 import Template

text = """
a_var -->
{% for obj in a -%}
{{ obj }}
{% endfor %}
b_var -->
{% for obj in b -%}
{% for k, v in obj.items() -%}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}
{% endfor -%}
{% endfor %}
c_var -->
{% for obj in c -%}
{% for k, v in obj.items() -%}
{{ k }}: {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
{% if not loop.last %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
"""

tpl = Template(text).render(a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

Output :

```
a_var -->
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

b_var -->
IP: 1.1.1.1
IP: 2.2.2.2
IP: 3.3.3.3

c_var -->
ID: dasfsdfs
IP: 1.1.1.1
Name: me

ID: qwrfgvzx
IP: 2.2.2.2
Name: you
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is nice way of achieving the same, though I think OP is new to Python so learning curve to learn Jinja2 template syntax is overhead as well as it's overhead for small tasks like this, which is in my opinion overkill compared to a straightforward Python loop.

Comment: I mean it's just basic loops, nothing fancy. But if you find it complicated, that's OK. And considering that the question is about *"inline for loops"*, Jinja might be a good fit, IDK, just saying ;)

Comment: Exactly my point (when it comes to nature of the OP's question), like you can't expect that he manages to get-along with Jinja2, if he still didn't go over the basics.